# Where is data from Software Update server located?

Tags: macos, osx-server, server.app

We have a Mac Mini running Server 4.0 and are using the Software Update service. Where are these file stored?

This was accidentally set to Automatic and we are wanting to just manually manage company updates. We turned the service off and removed the updates but the storage is still being used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard directory in Yosemite/Mavericks where the update packages are stored in folders and sub-folders is here:

```
"/Library/Server/Software Update/Data/html/content/downloads/"
```

The DocRoot may be customized though.

Entering the following in Terminal to get a previously *customized* `DocRoot` should work:

```
 /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'print :updatesDocRoot' "/Library/Server/Software Update/Config/swupd.plist"
```